# Preferences are not persisted in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, preferences

I've read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html), that Preferences are persisted automatically. I've tried to follow the instructions, but the checkbox always have its default value. My code goes as following:

1) I have a menu that opens Preferences screen:

```
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
          {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);
          }
```

2) Preferences Fragment class, that loads the settings:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_screen);
}
```

}

3) And activity, that loads the fragment:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
}
}
```

Preference Screen xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<CheckBoxPreference android:enabled="true" 
android:title="@string/ShowAdsTitle"  
android:summaryOn="@string/ShowAdsOnPreference" 
android:selectable="true" 
android:summaryOff="@string/ShowAdsOnPreference"
android:key="@string/value_showads_preference"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Somehow my settings are not persistent. android:key is set up for each of my settings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please include the xml file as well?

Comment: @vandus added the xml for the fragment

Comment: Try using it from a `PreferenceActivity`, rather than some other `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:key="value"/>
```

Try placing a direct string for android:key instead of a value from string as you will not be able to access translated key values

Comment: Tried this too, same outcome, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me so I am gonna describe my steps:

in MainActivity in onCreate:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PrefActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

This will open the Preferences Activity.

```
public class PrefActivity extends Activity
{
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
}
}
```

This will start the SettingsFragment.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_screen);
}
}
```

And this is the code for the settings xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="show ads"
    android:summaryOn="show ads on"
    android:selectable="true"
    android:summaryOff="show ads on"
    android:key="value"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I am not sure what kind of class is the Preferences.class but it might be the problem. Anyway, this code works and it nicely checks and unchecks the preference and keeps it that way after going back form and to it :)

Comment: Oh, I refactored the code in the middle of question :(. Edited it now. Preferences is PreferencesActivity. Also, didn't noticed any significant change in your code from mine.

Comment: what kind of device are you using for testing? what API level?

Comment: the preference_settings.xml is in xml folder in res folder

Comment: 1) Emulator with 14 and nexus 4 with 4.4.4 2) Yes: res\xml. I can see the preferences screen exactly as I want

Comment: Ok, I've copied the code to onUpdate. Now, if I leave app by home button - i return to activity and checkbox still in place. But when I go back and to settings again - checkbox disappears.

Comment: @Rajnish Mishra figured out what was that difference. The reason it worked on your PC and not on my.